Why does not work the await fetch to the API function?
I'm creating a AI chat using OpenAI API, i following this tutorial but the thing is when i made the call to the api/chat/sendMessage.js i get the 404 error, idk what to do, i made several OpenAI keys and still not working, here is te code in sendMessage.js
import { OpenAIEdgeStream } from "openai-edge-stream";


export const runtime = 'edge';

export default async function handler(req){
    try{
    const {message} = req.json;
    const stream= await OpenAIEdgeStream('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
    {
        headers:{'content-type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY}`
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages: [{content: message, role: "user"}],
            stream: true
        }) 
    }
    );
    return new Response(stream);
    
    }catch(e){
        console.log("Un error ha ocurrido al enviar el mensaje", e);
    }
}

And the page.tsx where i send the form(the message the user writes) to the api
"use client";
import Image from 'next/image';
import EmptyState from './components/EmptyState';
import Historial from './components/Historial';
import { useState } from 'react';
import {streamReader} from "openai-edge-stream";

export default function Home() {
  const [messageText, setMessageText] = useState("");
  
  const handleSumbit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("MessageText:", messageText);
    const response = await fetch("/api/chat/sendMessage", {
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({message: messageText}),
        
    });
    
    const data= response.body;
    //const data = await response.json();
    if(!response.ok){
      throw new Error("No sirve la api alv");   
    }
    const reader= data.getReader();
    await streamReader(reader, (message) =>{
        console.log("Message AI:", message)
    });
}

  return (
    <>
    <main className="h-full">
      
      <div className="flex flex-row h-full">
      <div className="w-[30px]">
          <Historial /> 
      </div>
      <div className=" lg:pl-[200px] w-full flex flex-col h-full " >
        <div className="flex-1 overflow-y-auto">
            Body!</div>
            <div >
            <form onSubmit={handleSumbit}> {/* style del form*/}
                <fieldset className="flex gap-2">
                    <textarea 
                    value={messageText}
                    onChange={(e) => setMessageText(e.target.value)}
                    placeholder="Send a Message..." 
                    className="w-full resize-none rounded-md bg-white p-2 text-black border-none focus:outline-none"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" className="rounded-full p-2 bg-[#2c4277] cursor-pointer hover:bg-[#23355e] transition w-[37px] h-[37px]">
                    <Image src="/enviar.png" alt="enviar" width={35} height={35} />
                    </button>
                </fieldset>
                
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    </>
  );
}

I tried change to response.json() and didn't work, i change several API keys and also give the 404.

Have you generated other Key in the OpenAI plataform? Maybe you copied wrong

404 error means usually a wrong end point. Make sure the end point or the url is correct.

What system is that handler function operating in? Next.js, AWS Lambda, something else? How are requests routed to it?

Judging by the client-side code, it's Next.js. Looks to me like you've confused API routes and route handlers. Please read the docs for both, decide which you're using and make sure the file path, name and handler function syntax are correct

you have a typo here:
const {message} = req.json(); // missing ()
so maybe your message type is incorrect then, hence 404 error
(just a guess)
